# MPV no audio issue

Tags: mpv-media-player

I installed MPV and I found that on playing any media file (mp3,mp4,webm etc.) doesn't play any audio.

I have tried to add in `mpv.conf` file :

```
# ===== Audio =====
ao=alsa
audio-device=auto
```

But still no audio.
What could be the issue ?

##### UPDATE 1

1. Output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*` :

```
abhishek@kamal:~$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
[sudo] password for abhishek: 
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  abhishek   1210 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  abhishek   1210 F.... pulseaudio
abhishek@kamal:~$
```

2. Output of `mpv -audio-device=help*` :

```
abhishek@kamal:~$ mpv -audio-device=help
List of detected audio devices:
  'auto' (Autoselect device)
  'pulse/alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo' (Built-in Audio Analog Stereo)
  'alsa' (Default (alsa))
  'alsa/samplerate' (Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library)
  'alsa/speexrate' (Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler)
  'alsa/jack' (JACK Audio Connection Kit)
  'alsa/oss' (Open Sound System)
  'alsa/upmix' (Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8))
  'alsa/vdownmix' (Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=7' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=8' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=9' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=10' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/sysdefault:CARD=PCH' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/Default Audio Device)
  'alsa/front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/Front output / input)
  'alsa/surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers)
  'alsa/surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers)
  'alsa/surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers)
  'alsa/surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers)
  'alsa/surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers)
  'alsa/surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=3' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=4' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0' (HDA Intel PCH, ALC256 Analog/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=3' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=7' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=8' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=9' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=10' (HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/usbstream:CARD=PCH' (HDA Intel PCH/USB Stream Output)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 0/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 1/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 2/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 3/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=10' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 4/Hardware device with all software conversions)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 0/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 1/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 2/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 3/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=4' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 4/HDMI Audio Output)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 0/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 1/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 2/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 3/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=10' (HDA NVidia, HDMI 4/Direct sample mixing device)
  'alsa/usbstream:CARD=NVidia' (HDA NVidia/USB Stream Output)
  'jack' (Default (jack))
  'sdl' (Default (sdl))
abhishek@kamal:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

After a long time, I found a solution:

1. Run this in terminal `mpv --audio-device=help`
   You will see some "list of detected audio devices".
2. Use above list and test one by one with audio-device as given below command:
   `mpv --audio-device=alsa/speexrate your_video.mp4` or
   `mpv --audio-device=alsa/vdownmix your_video.mp4` etc etc.

From the above test, you can find which audio-device is working for you.
Then open/create `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` and add given below content to the **mpv.conf** file:

```
# ===== Audio =====

osc=no
ao=alsa
audio-device=alsa/speexrate
```

And replace `alsa/speexrate` with the working option for you which you have tested above.